# jQuery code ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have the following code in a separate script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css('background-color', "#" + getRandomInt(10, 99) + getRandomInt(0, 99) + getRandomInt(0, 99));
    $('span').click(function(e) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            console.log('TESEEEEEEEEEEEEEEET');
        }
        var clicked_button = $(e.target);
        add_post_part(clicked_button);
    });
});

function add_post_part(clicked_button) {
    var number_of_post_parts = $('#content .post-part').length;


}

/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

This is the HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- basic stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/general.css">

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script language="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

        <!-- my own scripts -->
        <script language="text/javascript" src="static/js/post_parts.js"></script>

        <title>Blog Post</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <span>Title:</span><br>
            <textarea class="post-part post-title" id="post_part_0"></textarea><br>
            <input class="add-post-part-button" type="button" value="add part"/>
            <input class="remove-post-part-button" type="button" value="remove part"/><br><br>

            <span>Text:</span><br>
            <textarea class="post-part post-text" id="post_part_1"></textarea><br>
            <input class="add-post-part-button" type="button" value="add part"/>
            <input class="remove-post-part-button" type="button" value="remove part"/><br><br>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click the my own script name in the source code view of the html page, it propperly shows the script, so the browser (tried it with FF, OP, Chromium) finds it, however, no matter what I do, the code is never run.

I expected it to run when I click any `span` element on the page. Also I already tried to insert a simply `console.log("")` after the document ready, but that also is never executed.

What's wrong with my code? Did my browsers suddenly lose the ability to run local js files?

I've been trying for hours to get my browsers to log a simply output, but nothing seems to fix it. Starting to wonder if I am code blind or something.

**Edit#1:**
My console output when I reload the page:
`GET 
http://localhost:5000/makepost [HTTP/1.0 200 OK 2ms]
GET 
http://localhost:5000/static/css/general.css [HTTP/1.0 304 NOT MODIFIED 3ms]
GET 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 37ms]
GET 
http://localhost:5000/static/js/post_parts.js [HTTP/1.0 304 NOT MODIFIED 2ms]
JavaScript 1.6's for-each-in loops are deprecated; consider using ES6 for-of instead ScriptSurrogate.js:344:209
GET 
http://localhost:5000/static/img/bg/footer_lodyas.png [HTTP/1.0 304 NOT MODIFIED 2ms]`

**Edit#2:**
Solution was found in one of the answers here: it must be
`<script *type*="..." src="..."></script>`
and not
`<script *language*="..." src="..."></script>`

Appaerently I still had that language attribute somewhere in my head while it was used for something else.

Comment: did you look at the js debug console for errors?

Comment: No errors, only one deprication warning.

Comment: Please provide demo that replicates the problem

Comment: That's just the crazy thing about it (why I don't get it) - this *is* the demo code! The only thing missing is my css, do you think, that would add anything of value to the post?

Comment: I often debug js by adding "alert('Debug message');" to the code. You should try this. I think that script was executed.

Comment: See the solution for the reason why it didn't work : ) My faith in console.log is restored!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed:

```
 <script language="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does run, but console logging 10k times so it is locking up the browser for bit. Run this, click the title and you will see an alert that I added. I commented out the loop iterating 10k times.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css('background-color', "#" + getRandomInt(10, 99) + getRandomInt(0, 99) + getRandomInt(0, 99));
    $('span').click(function(e) {
        //for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        alert('TESEEEEEEEEEEEEEEET');
        //}
        var clicked_button = $(e.target);
        add_post_part(clicked_button);
    });
});

function add_post_part(clicked_button) {
    var number_of_post_parts = $('#content .post-part').length;


}

/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>Blog Post</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <span>Title:</span><br>
            <textarea class="post-part post-title" id="post_part_0"></textarea><br>
            <input class="add-post-part-button" type="button" value="add part"/>
            <input class="remove-post-part-button" type="button" value="remove part"/><br><br>

            <span>Text:</span><br>
            <textarea class="post-part post-text" id="post_part_1"></textarea><br>
            <input class="add-post-part-button" type="button" value="add part"/>
            <input class="remove-post-part-button" type="button" value="remove part"/><br><br>  
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I only added the 10000 thing to cause a lag or anything noticable, but it doesn't log anything nor does it lag or anything. This was one desperate attempt to get at least some reaction on the script. Here on SO your change works, but as soon as I take it into my file on my computer, it doesn't have any effect and still doesn't log anything.